# detect blue line with if statement

Tags: c++, opencv

I have made a blue line using OpenCV and Houghlines (in c++) and I was wondering what to include in an if statement that is supposed to detect if the blue line exists and if it does perform an action.

I was trying with the *cv::inRange* function to detect the blue, but I cannot use it in the if statement.

Here is the code to draw the blue lines:

```
         vector<Vec2f> lines;
         HoughLines(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100, 0, 0 ); 

        for(size_t i = 0;i < lines.size();i++)
         {
            float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];

            //scan only for horizontal line)
            if(theta > CV_PI/180*80 && theta < CV_PI/180*100){

            Point pt1, pt2;
            double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
            double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
            pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
            pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
            pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
            pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));

            //draw the line in blue
            cvLine(m_image, pt1, pt2, Scalar(255,0,0), 3, CV_AA);
            }
        }
    }
```

And basically what I want to do is

```
if (blue line exists) {
     do something
}
```

Here is the current image I am getting. (Ignore the green and red line, it is basically POV of car on the road) I am suppose to detect when blue line get in the lower part of the image (right in front of the picture) then perform the action (make the car stop)

[POV of the car](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pktau.png)

Thank you for your time.

PS. Thanks Saransh Kejriwal, I am trying with the Flag now.

Comment: how would the final image look like ?
can the image have similar color(s) at pixels other than where you are drawing line at?

Comment: I added the picture I am analyzing, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways you can follow:

1) set a flag when you draw a blue line:

Everytime you draw a blue line, set an int flag=1.

```
drawline();
flag=1;
```

This can be checked in the 'if' condition. So when flag is 1, that means you've drawn a blue line earlier. It is much neater, if it suits your requirement.

2) design a blue colour filter
In case you've drawn the blue line before you're calling the 'if' statement, here's the algorithm you follow,
-design a blue colour mask using inRange, and save the mask on the different Mat object (Mat mask;)
- Apply findContours on mask. Check contour area of each contour that you obtained.
- In case you have drawn a line, one of the contours will have a significant area, then you can apply if condition as:

```
if(contourArea(contours[i])>some_threshold_value)
{
     //your code here
}
```